# EF4.1 - Is there an issue using pre-generated views with TFS team builds on separate build server?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have an entity model build using EF4.1 code first, which uses a WCF Data service to expose the entities. To improve performance I have pre-generated the EF views. This works fine when I run locally, or if I publish the service using visual studio. However, when I use the TFS team build to create the service, I get the following error when try and access my entities via the data service:

**The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'X' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views.**

The TFS team build uses a separate build server to build the data service + entity model. The code being built is identical, the web.config + databases are also identical. This suggests that either the team build or the build server is altering either the view, the edmx file or the DbContext in some way.

Thanks in advance for any help

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a version mismatch between the EF4.1 dlls used on the dev servers and the dll used by the build server.  For a full explanation see this thread.

[EF Pre-Compiled Builds issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f28eb9da-8e76-46c0-993f-10be01081fed)